# 9 or 10 sec loading time for an Android app made with Buildozer/Python

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

When building a very simple app (coming from [touchtracer example app](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/touchtracer) here), one can notice a 9 or 10 seconds long loading time at each startup of the app.

**Is this inherent to an app built with Python/Buildozer?** (because the Python interpreter contained in the app has to open itself, etc.)

Or is there a way to make an Android app coded in Python start in less than 3 seconds? Maybe https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android looks as a different solution to Buildozer.

Comment: Buildozer uses python-for-android. So it's probably not an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The startup time depends on the device and can be much faster than that on some newer ones, but the general issue is fundamental to the way python-for-android currently works.

That said, the first run of the app will take longer (sometimes several seconds longer) due to unpacking some files. This is only done once, so subsequent starts are faster. The time taken for this again depends on the device, and in particular depends on the speed of the filesystem.

Regarding buildozer vs python-for-android, buildozer is a wrapper to python-for-android that handles some dependencies which aren't managed by python-for-android itself. Buildozer also allows building for ios using the same unified config.